# Can Express routes be used as MVC Controllers in Node.JS Apps?

Tags: node.js, express

I have been playing around for a bit on Nodejs, so forgive me if my question might look stupid.

When I setup a new nodejs app with express, I noted that it created a folder /routes that basically does what it suggests.

Now, is it ok to use said file(s) as the Controllers for my app?

Answer (score 0):

I think so. Because role of a route in express is to decide what to do when a certain request comes, such as getting data from a model or rendering a view with some data and this is what controllers do, right?

You can see in official examples that routes are actually placed in a folder named `conrollers`.

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/mvc/controllers/pet/index.js